# consecutive days constraint in linear programming

Tags: optimization, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

For a work shift optimization problem, I've defined a binary variable in PuLP as follows:

```
pulp.LpVariable.dicts('VAR', (range(D), range(N), range(T)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
```

where

1. D = # days in each schedule we create (=28, or 4 weeks)
2. N = # of workers
3. T = types of work shift (=6)

For the 5th and 6th type of work shift (with index 4 and 5), I need to add a constraint that any worker who works these shifts must do so for seven consecutive days... and not any seven days but the seven days starting from Monday (aka a full week). I've tried defining the constraint as follows, but I'm getting an infeasible solution when I add this constraint and try to solve the problem (it worked before without it)

I know this constraint (along with the others from before) should theoretically be feasible because we *manually* schedule work shifts with the same set of constraints. Is there anything wrong with the way I've coded the constraint?

```
## looping over each worker
for j in range(N):
    ## looping for every Monday in the 28 days 
    for i in range(0,D,7):
        c = None
        ## accessing only the 5th and 6th work shift type 
        for k in range(4,T):
            c+=var[i][j][k]+var[i+1][j][k]+var[i+2][j][k]+var[i+3][j][k]+var[i+4][j][k]+var[i+5][j][k]+var[i+6][j][k]
        problem+= c==7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then your constraint requires that each worker is required to work the 4th and 5th shift in every week. This is because of `c == 7`, i.e. 7 of the binaries in `c` must be set to 1. This does not allow any worker to work in shift 0 through 3, right?

You need to change the constraint so that `c == 7` is only enforced if the worker works any shift in that range. A very simple way to do that would be something like

```
v = list()
for k in range(4,T):
  v.extend([var[i][j][k], var[i+1][j][k], var[i+2][j][k], var[i+3][j][k], var[i+4][j][k], var[i+5][j][k], var[i+6][j][k]])
c = sum(v)
problem += c <= 7        # we can pick at most 7 variables from v
for x in v:
  problem += 7 * x <= c  # if any variable in v is picked, then we must pick 7 of them
```

This is by no means the best way to model that (indicator variables would be much better), but it should give you an idea what to do.

Comment: thanks for the response, appreciate it! maybe i didn't understand your code properly, but the constraint is closer to (removing the 4th and 5th shift caveat for clarity): for any worker who works shift A, they must do so for the whole week (a.k.a var[i][j][k], var[i+1][j][k], ..., var[i+6][j][k] must all equal 1 for k = A if any were to be = 1 in the first place for person j). not sure what the list extension is doing. would appreciate further clarity!

Comment: hey, I tried implementing the solution and with a few changes it worked marvels! still would love to know why though ahah

Comment: Ok, with your updated description, I think you just have to move everything into the `k` loop: 1. Construct the list `v` of all variables that correspond to shift A, the current worker and the current week. 2. Compute `c = sum(v)`. 3. Add `problem += c <= 7`. 4. Add constraints for each variable in `v`: `for x in v: problem += 7 * x <= c`. I think that should state your constraints on a per-shift basis. The trick is `7 * x <= c`: If at least one `x` variable is 1 (i.e., worker works shift A in this week), then all variables in `c` are forced to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative approach, assuming (as I read it) that for any given week a worker can either work some combination of shifts in [0:3] across the seven days, or one of the shifts [4:5] every day: we can do this by defining a new binary variable Y[w][n][t] which is 1 if in week w worker n does a restricted shift t, 0 otherwise. Then we can relate this variable to our existing variable X by adding constraints so that the values X can take depend on the values of Y.

```
# Define the sets of shifts
non_restricted_shifts = [0,1,2,3]
restricted_shifts = [4,5]

# Define a binary variable Y, 1 if for week w worker n works restricted shift t
Y = LpVariable.dicts('Y', (range(round(D/7)), range(N), restricted_shifts), cat=LpBinary)

# If sum(Y[week][n][:]) = 1, the total number of non-restricted shifts for that week and n must be 0
for week in range(round(D/7)):
    for n in range(N):
        prob += lpSum(X[d][n][t] for d in range(week*7, week*7 + 7) for t in non_restricted_shifts) <= 1000*(1-lpSum(Y[week][n][t] for t in restricted_shifts))

# If worker n has 7 restricted shift t in week w, then Y[week][n][t] == 1, otherwise it is 0
for week in range(round(D/7)):
    for n in range(N):
        for t in restricted_shifts:
            prob += lpSum(X[d][n][t] for d in range(week*7, week*7+7)) <= 7*(Y[week][n][t]) 
            prob += lpSum(X[d][n][t] for d in range(week*7, week*7+7)) >= Y[week][n][t]*7
```

Some example output (D=14, N=2, T=6):

```
        / M T W T F S S / M T W T F S S / M T W T F S S / M T W T F S S
WORKER 0
Shifts: / 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 / 1 0 2 3 2 2 0 / 3 1 2 2 3 1 1 / 2 3 0 3 3 0 3
WORKER 1
Shifts: / 3 1 2 3 1 1 2 / 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 / 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 / 1 3 2 2 3 2 1
WORKER 2
Shifts: / 1 2 3 1 3 1 1 / 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 / 3 2 3 0 3 1 0 / 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
WORKER 3
Shifts: / 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 / 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 / 3 1 3 1 0 3 1 / 2 2 2 2 3 0 3
WORKER 4
Shifts: / 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 / 3 3 1 0 2 3 3 / 0 3 3 3 3 0 2 / 3 3 3 2 3 2 3
```